# UITableViewController and UIColor change position when scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicolor

hi guys i have a normal UITableViewController with some cell inside,
i have just 1 cell that has this property:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```

it show me a gray color on a cell (good).

The problem comes when i use the scroller, (i tap on the window and i go down for see 
other cells) in this case the Gray color of the cell move (insanely) from the Position where it was
to another cell.

why ??

the code:

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

if(cell.backgroundColor == [UIColor lightGrayColor])
{
   cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}
else
{
   cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
switch (currentStatus) {
    case KBI_NAME:
    {
        switch (indexPath.section) {
            case 0:
            {
                if(indexPath.row == 0)
                {
                    if (currentUser.currentKBI != nil && ![currentUser.currentKBI isEqualToString:@""]) {
                        cell.textLabel.text = currentUser.currentKBI;
                    }
                    else{
                        cell.textLabel.text = @"asdf";
                    }  

                    cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

                    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
                }
                if(indexPath.row == 1)
                {
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"xyz";
                    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
                }

                break;
            }
            case 1:
```

Comment: Yet another update with a somewhat simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scroll in a `UITableView`, cells that are scrolled out of view are reused for cells that scroll into view. That's what the following line is for:

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
```

So if this line returns a cell, you need to set the background color every time because you might have gotten the cell with the gray background.

```
if (isGrayCell)
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
else
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

**Update**

Your code for setting the background color doesn't make sense. If the recycled cell has a gray background, you set it to gray again even if you need a different color. Those like should look something like this:

```
if(currentStatus == KBI_NAME && indexPath.row == 0)
{
   cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}
else
{
   cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

**Update 2**

It's probably much easier, if you simply initialize the cell every time:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

If you need a gray background, the color is later changed again to gray.

Comment: i already set the background every time. i don't get the answer

Comment: ok now the gray stay in the same position dose not move, but the other cells Still insanely change colors

Comment: Please add the full code of the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to your question. Without the code, it's just guessing.

Comment: i did add your code after if (cell == nil) { ... } but don't seem work